# Exception Occured com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am Having hard time with JBDC connectivity. I don't know where I doing wrong? Please help me point out where I have done mistake and what's the reason behind Exception error: Exception occured com.mysql.jdbc

```
private void btnInsertActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)            
{
  String code = txtCode.getText();
  String name = txtName.getText();
  String cell_num = txtCell.getText();
  String adrs = txtAdd.getText();

 Connection conn = null;
 try{
      Class.forName("com.sql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
  catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception Occured"+e.getMessage());
    }

 try{conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ManagementSystem"+","+ user);

    String query ="INSERT INTO EmployeeForm1(EmployeeCode,Name,Cell_No, Address) VALUES('"+code+","+name+","+cell_num+","+ "'" + adrs+"')";

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        resultSet.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY");
     }catch(SQLException se){
  //Handle errors for JDBC
         se.printStackTrace();
     }catch(Exception e){
  //Handle errors for Class.forName
         e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
  //finally block used to close resources
         try{
             if(conn!=null)
                 conn.close();
         }catch(SQLException se){
             se.printStackTrace();
         }//end finally try
}                                         
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ManagementSystem,root
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
at managementsystem1.EmployeeForm.btnInsertActionPerformed(EmployeeForm.java:120)
at managementsystem1.EmployeeForm.access$000(EmployeeForm.java:12)
at managementsystem1.EmployeeForm$1.actionPerformed(EmployeeForm.java:53)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)`
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace!  We are not mind readers.

Comment: have you included driver in your classpath? and i guess you have provided incorrect name for the driver. EDIT: i think there's some syntax error in the `getConnection` parameters as well. i'm not sure if it is okay.

Comment: Yeah I have included drive in classpath but still getting errors. This is a Swing program which is getting input from textFields.

Comment: You haven't needed the Class.forName() line for about ten years. Just remove it, and the try/catch around it, of course. If the correct JAR is on the CLASSPATH it will be found via the database URL. NB there must have been a prior error from that line which you have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple typo :) You have:

`Class.forName("com.sql.jdbc.Driver");`

This should be:

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` <-- notice com.**mysql** instead of com.**sql**

The reason for this is because the MySQL driver adds itself to the DriverManager registry in a static block when the ClassLoader loads the class. By calling Class.forName (or depending on the class via an import, etc.) you are explicitly asking Java to load it, thus registering the mysql jdbc namespace in DriverManager.

See the [MySQL Connector/J Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html). Also, see an old version of the [MySQL Driver class source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.java.html) to view the static block registering the driver with DriverManager.

Answer (score -1):

Add "mysql-connector-5.1.6.jar" into your java's classpath. If you are facing any problem or putting the jar in java's class path dosnt reflect then try building the project under Eclipse IDE

In eclipse under "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path .."
add external jar which would be "mysql-connector-5.1.6.jar"

Comment: I am using netbeans and I have added mysql-connector-5.1.6.jar into classpath but it's still giving exception errors. OK now I am trying to check the problem in eclipse let's see if it works in eclipse.

Comment: I am still getting exception error in eclipse. when I run the JFrame Form and click the Insert button it gives exception error!

Comment: Why 5.1.6? It's *six years* out of date. @Amjad You should use the *latest* version, which is at least 5.5.30.

Comment: Because you told him to use a six-year-old software release, which you haven't even attempted to explain, despite my question about it. NB There's a typo in my comment. It should be 5.1.30. Still no less than *twenty-four* releases later.